# How to tell if my led strip is busted?

Tags: electrical, led

I recently ordered an led strip off of amazon and i hooked it up to a 19v power supply. it turned on suddenly and then turned off. Did i botch my new led strip? how can i tell if i really did. I disconnected it from that PSU and connected is to an 12v as other people did in the comments section on amazon did, but the lights would not turn on.

Comment: Post the model of LED strip as it will help identify what is being looked at.

Comment: Most of those strips are 12v... if you had one of those, 19v would destroy it.

Comment: it was 12v so i assume its busted. I paid 22 dollars lol. I learned not to do that again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was it very bright, once, and now it doesn't light?  That was you frying it.

LED strips do not have switching regulators on them, current limiting is done by dumb resistors.  They are running at absolute limits on 13.8V which is float voltage for an automotive alternator.

Looks like you're out $22.  Sorry.

Now if you really need to run off 19v, you can buy a type of LED strip designed to run on 24V.  Those will be notably dim, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thank you for the inforation, i purchase the  proper PSU.

Comment: @ChrisAscencio They do make a variation of those LED strips which is 24V instead of 12V.  Most amplifiers and some dimmer/color controllers are able to work on both 12 and 24 volts.  It will be significantly dimmer, the question is whether it'll be too dim.

Answer (score 0):

LEDs need to be driven using constant current source.

When you connected a constant voltage (regulated voltage) power supply, the excessive in-rush current may have destroyed the LEDs on your strip.

Here is a CC LED driver picture from eBay:

[image]